# How to change the colour of a rectangle present in a XAML grid cell if i know the grid cell position using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a XAML grid that i have produced dynamically and have inserted rectangle objects in each cell so that i can change their color as i want afterwards. 
What i am not being able to figure out is how to access the rectangle objects in C# when i want to if i only know the cell row and column number to be accessed and the grid name.
I have tried inserting new Rectangle objects over existing ones but in my code that gives me a stack overflow exception.
Any help would be much appreciated.

XAML CODE-

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" x:Name="AnswerGrid" Width="500" Height="400" Margin="2"
    Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
</Grid>
```

C# rectangle objects in grid-

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
Grid.SetRow(rect, i);
Grid.SetColumn(rect, j);
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.AliceBlue);
AnswerGrid.Children.Add(rect);
```

i am populating this grid dynamically with rows,columns and rectangle objects in each cell.I want to change the background color of the rectangle in a particular cell.

Comment: You need to paste the xaml/C# code that you are using before we can help you..

Comment: Please check again

Comment: "I have tried inserting new Rectangle objects over existing ones but in my code that gives me a stack overflow exception" - You should also show us the code you have tried which is causing the errors. Nevertheless, I have given an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the rectangles some how, either by accessing it from the existing grid, or using a dictionary to find the rectangle like so

```
    Dictionary<int, Rectangle> _rectDict = new Dictionary<int, Rectangle>();
    int _maxCol = 10;

    private void AddRectangle(int i, int j)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        Grid.SetRow(rect, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(rect, j);
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.AliceBlue);
        AnswerGrid.Children.Add(rect);

        _rectDict[i * _maxCol + j] = rect;
    }

    private void ChangeColour(int i, int j, Color color)
    {
        Rectangle rect = _rectDict[i * _maxCol + j];

        // Change colour of rect
    }
```

Keeping a dictionary like this will likely be easier and cheaper than trying to find the Rectangle via the grid's children